# How should the framerate be regulated on an android game?

Tags: android, frame-rate, thread-sleep

I've created a simple game on android that has the basic updatePhysics() and onDraw() in the main game loop. Initially, I didn't put anything to keep a consistent framerate, so it would loop infinitely without sleeping. But after doing some research, I found that it would probably be better to regulate this so that the framerate is consistent. So I put Thread.sleep() in to make it go at around 30 fps. Here's the code:

```
if(!h.getSurface().isValid())
    continue;
synchronized(h){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(state == STATE_GAME){
        updatePhysics();
    }
    onDraw();
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try{
    Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME - (endTime - startTime));
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

What I found was my game became really choppy, it wasn't 30 fps at all, more like around 20. However, if I increased that rate to around 40, then it would look like 30 fps(Becomes smoother). I read online that games are usually 25 - 30 fps so I assume 40 may be a bit too high. Am I doing something wrong, am I supposed to use Thread.sleep()? And also, if I run this without regulating the fps, how would it affect other devices? It runs smooth on my galaxy s2 without the Thread.sleep(), and the inconsistent framerate is not noticeable. But I'm concerned with the lower end devices. What do high end games like angry birds do? Thanks for any answers I'm very new to game development.